# How to calculate average on a subset of a subset of a dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to calculate the average of a subset of a subset of data.

For example, imagine my data is

```
 **Family Name / Gender / Grade**
    Smith / Male / 90
    Smith / Male / 85
    Smith / Female / 65
    Smith / Female / 100
    Johns / Male / 95
    Johns / Male / 45
    Johns / Female / 20
    Johns / Female / 100
```

So what I am trying to do is calculate the average grades of the females in the Smith family. The answer would be (65+100)/2.

I know how to calculate it the mean, but I do not know how to break it into subcategories twice.

My code is:

```
numpy.mean(students.grade)
```

I also tried a method where I did:

```
smith_family = students[students['Family Name'] == 'Smith']
np.mean(smith_family.grades)
```

But this method isn't scalable because I would have to manually type in every family name.

I made up the data; I'm actually doing it with animals and people's ratings of animals but its the same concept.

P.S. I'm using Python.

Answer (score 2):

You'll use `groupby` here:

```
students[students['Family Name'] == 'Smith'].groupby('Gender').Grade.mean()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can

```
df.set_index(['FamilyName','Gender']).mean(level=[0,1])
Out[271]: 
                   Grade
FamilyName Gender       
Smith      Male     87.5
           Female   82.5
Johns      Male     70.0
           Female   60.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of typing in every family name (which would be tedious as you mentioned) you can just groupby the name column. Additionally, you can do a second level groupby using gender to give combinations of both name and gender. Then calculate the mean for each subgroup:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Smith', 'Smith', 'Smith', 'Smith', 'Johns', 'Johns', 'Johns', 'Johns'],
                   'Gender': ['Male', 'Male', 'Female', 'Female', 'Male', 'Male', 'Female', 'Female'],
                   'Grade': [90, 85, 65, 100, 95, 45, 20, 100]})

df.groupby(['Name', 'Gender']).mean()
```

Which will give you:

```
              Grade
Name  Gender       
Johns Female   60.0
      Male     70.0
Smith Female   82.5
      Male     87.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby`!

`students = pd.DataFrame({'Family Name': ['Smith', 'Smith', 'Smith', 'Smith', 'Johns', 'Johns', 'Johns', 'Johns'], 'Gender': ['Male', 'Male', 'Female', 'Female', 'Male', 'Male', 'Female', 'Female'], 'Grade': [90, 85, 65, 100, 95, 45, 20, 100]})`

`students.groupby(['Family Name', 'Gender']).mean()`

[Here's a link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to the documentation for `pandas.DataFrame.groupby`. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

use `Groupby` method in Pandas. First convert the array to a DataFrame object

`df = pandas.DataFrame(values, index=index)`

then group by the family name and calculate the mean or sum for each group.

`df.groupby('Family Name').mean()`

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that you have a jumble of strings, family name, gender, and grade, that aren't organized at all and, as a result, you are struggling to figure
out how to make sense of it all. Here is a time where object-oriented programming is excellent.

Rather than storing a bunch of variables:

```
    family_name_1 = "smith"
    gender_1 = "male"
    grade_1 = 95
    family_name_2 = "johns"
    #...
```

You could create a class, called, say, Person, with three instance variables:

```
    class Person:

        family_name

        gender

        grade
```

Now, your class needs a constructor, so you could make a Person and tell the program what that specific Person's family name, gender, and grade are. Inside your code for the class, you will need something like this:

```
    def __init__(self, family_name, gender, grade):
        self.family_name = family_name
        self.gender = gender
        self.grade = grade
```

Now, you are finished setting up your Person class. Next, you are going to want to populate by creating new people:

```
    bob = Person("smith", "male", 95)
```

Not only is this easier to type than what was above, your code is now much more organized. The next thing you'll need is a list of people so you can average them together:

```
    people = [Person("smith", "female", 97), Person("johns", "male", 60)] #...
```

For averaging all the people's grade's, I actually wouldn't use numpy, rather, something like this:

```
    total = 0
    number = 0
    for person in people:
        if person.gender == "female" and person.family_name == "smith":
            total += person.grade
            number += 1
    average = total / number
    print average
```

If you feed all of your data as I did above into the list, and use my for loop, you should get the average of all the grades of all the Smith females. I hope you understand, and, please, someone correct me if my syntax is wrong - it's been awhile since I've used Python!